# how to deal with numerical variables like branch_id or state_id?

Tags: python, machine-learning

There a few columns like branch_id or state_id or country_id. These arent unique values for each row like id.

How to deal with such columns while working on a machine learning project?

I usually just convert them into nominal categories

```
train.branch_id = train.branch_id.astype('category',ordered =False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to [LabelEncode](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) or [OneHotEncode](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) them (usually the latter).

The simplest way of doing this is [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html).

Say you have a Series like the following:

```
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))

Output:
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
```

And then:

```
pd.get_dummies(s)

Output:
    a   b   c
0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   1
3   1   0   0
```

This then goes into your train data set as separate features.

However, be careful of [this trap](https://www.algosome.com/articles/dummy-variable-trap-regression.html) if you are doing a regression model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if the number of unique values is in the 1000's for that column is in the 1000's?

Comment: you can apply dimensionality reduction afterwards.

Comment: That's something I can try. Thank you.